# dmesg follow in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, dmesg

Is there a way to watch [dmesg](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/dmesg/) in realtime on FreeBSD like using the `--follow` (`-w`) option on `dmesg` in Linux?

Answer (score 7):

The way to watch the kernel message log in FreeBSD is not with `dmesg` at all.  `dmesg` is based around `sysctl()` which does not present a followable interface.  Rather, `sysctl()` only takes snapshots of the current kernel message buffer.

To follow the message log, one instead opens `/dev/klog` and polls the file descriptor (with `kevent()` or suchlike) for reading.  Only one program on the system can do this at any one time, as reading is destructive.  This program will be `syslogd` or something like the nosh toolset's `klog-read`.

One thus, rather, follows the outputs of those programs.  With `klog-read` this is effectively following the kernel message log as-is.  With `syslogd`, the system administrator may have configured kernel logs to be delivered in parts to various places.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Handling old log mechanisms](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/old-log-services.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Logging cheatsheet](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/logging-cheatsheet.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Answer (score 4):

FreeBSD's [dmesg](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/dmesg/) does not have a --follow (-w) switch but you can follow the output by using tail as follows: `tail -F /var/log/messages`

Source for answer: [FreeBSD Forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/see-dmesg-as-it-updates.70729/)

Note: Updated to use `-F` instead of `-f` as per suggestion from @Mateusz Piotrowski

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might want to use `tail -F /var/log/messages` instead of `tail -f /var/log/messages` so that the file is going to be followed even if it got renamed or rotated. See the [tail(1)](http://man.freebsd.org/tail) manual page for the complete description of the `-F` flag.